# Iptsbles site to site vpn

Tags: iptables, vpn, firewall, nat, site-to-site-vpn

I have installed strongswan site-to-site vpn,thats working fine. On server I have configured iptables with this commans `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.141.0/24 -d 10.10.27.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`.

Is another way to set up this without masquarade?

I want use routing between network1 and network2 for monitoring of running clients by ip.

Thank you